# My iphone for the first time vibrate twice for one message

Tags: messages

I was talking in face time with my husband and he sent me a message to I message, my phone vibrated but there wasn't a sms or notifications for the sms.

After 3 seconds my phone vibrate again and then show the sms.

The question is how can iphone 5 vibrate twice for same sms.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you could disable the "Repeat" in

go to settings > notifications >  select messages  > scroll down to repeat alerts > select never /.

Comment: Yeah I did it,It was once now its never but I still cant know which was the problem. :( It happens anyone of you